# Rails 3 - Can't figure out Create/Update form clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm using the same page to do my Create and Update form have this code right at the top of my page:

This works:

```
<% if @media.blank? %>
  <%= form_for(:media, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %> 
<% end %>
```

This doesn't:

```
<% if @media.blank? %>
  <%= form_for(:media, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %> 
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(:media, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @media.id}) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

The latter gives me this result:
syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end');  else

Should I be doing my create & update in a different way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if @media.blank? %>
  <%= form_for(:media, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
  <% end %> 
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(:media, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @media.id}) do |f| %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. So doing it this way I'd need to have 2 forms then? Or simple call a _form.html.erb page and include that I guess?

Comment: Yes doing this way you'll need 2 forms or render a partial two times However your question is thought-provoking because `form_for` is a method that accepts block (`do |f| ... end`) and I can't say for sure is it possible to have a block in a partial or a helper to pass it to `form_for`

Comment: Hmmm weird... I'm used to PHP and I guess I just need to follow how Rails works instead. I went with rendering the partial form twice. Thanks for the quick response, I appreciate it!